# Create a patch APK file

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Assume that "app-v1.apk" has assets/a.png. user install this app.
then we delete "a.png" file from assets and generate "app-v2.apk" file.
Is there any way to access the "assets/a.png" file when the user updates the app?

Comment: your question is not clear at all

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the question right, but when you upload an apk to the play store that already has a previous version it is handled as an update for the user

Comment: @AbdulKawee Sorry to disturb again. I've edited my question. would you please look at my question again?

Comment: @SeyyedMojtaba do check my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, what you are trying to say is

> can we access assets of previous build that are not present in current build?

As far as my knowledge goes, The answer is **NO**. Play store manages updates so when you upload the new `apk` playstore updates app with current build, so the assets or changes in the old build are not accessible anymore.

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: Thanks that sounds reasonable. But I've seen apps that have a lower file size of updates than a fresh install. I used the "Bazaar" (an android marketplace application in Iran).

Comment: @SeyyedMojtaba yes thats absolutely possible, you can use `Analyze APK` feature of `Android Studio` to find which files or libraries or assets are taking more space in your apk, and then you can shrink or change those libraries in update to reduce update size

Comment: No I mean it seemed that Bazaar used separate files for update and install. the update file size was way less than fresh install one.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not a good idea. You have to provide a complete app to take into account new users. Moreover, Play Store is able to update an app incrementally so you don't have to care about duplication for your users

Comment: Sorry... I've edited my question. can you check it again?

Comment: My answer is still valid. Don't care about it, the Play Store will do it for you

Comment: I know the Play store would do that, but I want to reduce the file size. but it seems that android system every time deletes the app folder and therefore former files will be deleted.